# child_removed doesn't always fire on firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm running two tests in firebase.  One version passes, the other does not.  The child_removed callback works fine if it's attached before the child is actually added.  It does not fire when attached after the insert.

Version that passes the test:

```
it("A) listens to child_removed raw (Before Insert)", function (done) {
  this.timeout(5000);

  let ref = DataServices.database.ref();
  let pushRef = ref.child('test/testChildRemovedA').push();
  let newKey = pushRef.key;
  let insertPath = 'test/testChildRemovedA/' + newKey;

  let callback = (snapshot) => { done(); }
  DataServices.database.ref('test/testChildRemovedA/').on("child_removed", callback);

  let updates = {};
  updates[insertPath] = 'hi';
  DataServices.database.ref().update(updates).then(() => {
      updates[insertPath] = null;
      DataServices.database.ref().update(updates);
    });
});
```

Version that fails the test:

```
it("B) listens to child_removed raw (After Insert)", function (done) {
  this.timeout(10000);

  let ref = DataServices.database.ref();
  let pushRef = ref.child('test/testChildRemovedB').push();
  let newKey = pushRef.key;
  let insertPath = 'test/testChildRemovedB/' + newKey;

  let callback = (snapshot) => { done(); }
  let updates = {};
  updates[insertPath] = 'hi';
  DataServices.database.ref().update(updates).then(() => {
      DataServices.database.ref('test/testChildRemovedB/').on("child_removed", callback);
      updates[insertPath] = null;
      DataServices.database.ref().update(updates);
    });
});
```

The only difference is where the child_removed event is attached, but both are attached before the data is actually deleted.  In both cases, the data is indeed removed from firebase.

Is there a race condition when adding the child_removed listener?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need any callback.  The code should be pretty simple.

[Retrieve Data on the Web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/retrieve-data)

> The `child_removed` event is triggered when an immediate child is
>   removed. It is typically used in conjunction with the child_added and
>   child_changed events. The snapshot passed to the event event contains
>   the data for the removed child.
>
> The `child_changed` event is triggered any time a child node is
>   modified. This includes any modifications to descendants of the child
>   node. It is typically used in conjunction with the child_added and
>   child_removed events to respond to changes to a list of items. The
>   snapshot passed to the event listener contains the updated data for
>   the child.
>
> ```
> var commentsRef = firebase.database().ref('post-comments/' + postId);
> commentsRef.on('child_added', function(data) {
>   addCommentElement(postElement, data.key, data.val().text, data.val().author);
> });
>
> commentsRef.on('child_changed', function(data) {
>   setCommentValues(postElement, data.key, data.val().text, data.val().author);
> });
>
> commentsRef.on('child_removed', function(data) {
>   deleteComment(postElement, data.key);
> });
> ```